# Find the equation of the chord joining points $p$ and $q$ on the parabola $x=2t$, $y=t^2$ if $p$ and $q$ are the roots of the equation $t^2-4t+2=0$

Tags: conic-sections

I have the answer but do not know the process in achieving it.
Find the equation of the chord joining points $p$ and $q$ on the parabola $x=2t$, $y=t^2$ if $p$ and $q$ are the roots of the equation $t^2-4t+2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$x=2t,  \ y=t^2$$ $$\implies x^2=4y$$

Now, solving $t^2-4t+2=0$, we get $$t=\frac{-(-4)\pm\sqrt{(-4)^2-4(1)(2)}}{2(1)}$$ $$t=\frac{4\pm 2\sqrt 2}{2}=2\pm\sqrt 2$$

Setting the values of $t$, we get the coordinates of the points P & Q as follows $$P(2t, t^2)\equiv (4+ 2\sqrt 2,\ 6+4\sqrt 2 )$$ & 
$$Q(2t, t^2)\equiv (4- 2\sqrt 2,\ 6-4\sqrt 2 )$$

I hope you can find out the equation of the chord PQ passing through the points $P(4+ 2\sqrt 2,\ 6+4\sqrt 2 )$ & $Q(4- 2\sqrt 2,\ 6-4\sqrt 2 )$ using formula
$$y-(6+4\sqrt 2)=\frac{(6+4\sqrt 2)-(6-4\sqrt 2)}{(4+2\sqrt 2)-(4-2\sqrt 2)}(x-(4+ 2\sqrt 2))$$
$$y-(6+4\sqrt 2)=2(x-4-2\sqrt 2)$$
$$y=2x-2$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{equation of the chord PQ:}\ \ \color{blue}{2x-y-2=0}}}$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Can you obtain the equation of the chord joining $P$ and $Q$ in terms of $p$ and $q$?

You will find the formula involves both $p+q$ and $pq$, which can be read off the quadratic given:

$p+q$ is the sum of roots, therefore 4.

$pq$ is the product of roots, therefore 2

Answer (score 0):

Use *Lagrange's interpolation polynomial:*: the chord must pass through the points $(2p,p^2)$ and $(2q,q^2)$, hence the equation is:
$$y=p^2\frac{x-2q}{2p-2q}+q^2\frac{x-2p}{2q-2p}=\frac{(p^2-q^2)x-2pq(p-q)}{2(p-q)}=\frac{p+q}2x-pq$$
Using Vieta's relations: $p+q=4,\ pq=2$, it gives the equation:
$$y=2(x-1).$$